# How to access Storage from frame_system::Config?

Tags: rust, substrate

I'm trying to convert the `utxo.rs` of Substrate's utxo-workshop to FRAME v2.

Here's a snippet that errors out at `<Number<T>>` (Because Number is private?).

```rust
#[frame_support::pallet]
pub mod pallet {
    #[pallet::pallet]
    #[pallet::generate_store(pub(super) trait Store)]
    pub struct Pallet<T>(PhantomData<T>);

    #[pallet::config]
    pub trait Config: frame_system::Config {
        /// The overarching event type.
        type Event: From<Event<Self>> + IsType<<Self as frame_system::Config>::Event>;

    }

    fn disperse_reward(authorities: &[H256]) {
      ...

      let hash = BlakeTwo256::hash_of(&(
        &utxo,
        <Number<T>>::get().unwrap().saturated_into::<u64>()
        ));

      ...
    }
}
```

Following the line to call the [block_number()](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/utxo-workshop/blob/master/runtime/src/utxo.rs#L254), I believe that's equivalent to [the block_number getter of FRAME v2](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/e98aca335f066d84d7a5cbabf280392f39e1cc99/frame/system/src/lib.rs#L568). It is accessible when you construct the runtime:

```rust
frame_support::construct_runtime!(
    pub enum Test 
    {
        System: frame_system::{Pallet, Call, Config, Storage, Event<T>},
        ...
    }
);

fn testing() {
   let block_number = System::block_number();
}
```

*But*, is there a way to access the Storage value on `frame_system::Config`, **without** the `construct_runtime!` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are able to access a runtime pallet's storage once the runtime is built, process done by the macro `construct_runtime!{}`. As you can read here https://substrate.dev/rustdocs/v3.0.0-monthly-2021-05/frame_support/macro.construct_runtime.html
A pallet that doesn't appear in that macro won't be part of your runtime, and so its storage will not be accessible.